# Twig : Unset element from array

Tags: twig

I have an array of elements composed of key => value for example:

`arr = { 156 : 'one', 99 : 'tow' }`

I want to remove an element from the array depending on the key. Like doing unset() in php ? Is it possible ?

Comment: It's not optimal doing this within twig. It's better to remove it before.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can also use the [filter pipe](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/filter.html) like this:

```
{% set arr = arr | filter((v, k) => k != '99') %}
```

Comment: Thank you @Oliver for your great answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can extend `twig` to do this

```
<?php
    class Project_Twig_Extension extends \Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension {

    public function getFunctions(){
        return [
            new \Twig\TwigFunction('unset', [$this, 'unset'], [ 'needs_context' => true, ]),
        ];
    }
    /**
    * $context is a special array which hold all know variables inside 
    * If $key is not defined unset the whole variable inside context
    * If $key is set test if $context[$variable] is defined if so unset $key inside multidimensional array
    **/
    public function unset(&$context, $variable, $key = null) {
        if ($key === null) unset($context[$variable]);
        else{
            if (isset($context[$variable])) unset($context[$variable][$key]);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage inside `twig`:

```html
<h1>Unset</h1>

{% set foo = 'bar' %}
{% set bar = { 'foo' : 'bar', } %}

<h2>Before</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>foo</td><td>{{ foo | default('not applicable') }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>bar.foo</td><td>{{ bar.foo | default('not applicable') }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>

{% do unset('foo') %}
{% do unset('bar', 'foo') %}

<h2>After</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>foo</td><td>{{ foo | default('not applicable') }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>bar.foo</td><td>{{ bar.foo | default('not applicable') }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

*output*

```
Before
|------------------------------|------------------------------|
| foo                          | bar                          |
| bar.foo                      | bar                          |
|------------------------------|------------------------------|


After
|------------------------------|------------------------------|
| foo                          | not applicable               |
| bar.foo                      | not applicable               |
|------------------------------|------------------------------|
```

Comment: How can I remove all the elements of an array and leave the array empty?

Comment: Better you asked this in a new question as it's not really related but u could do `{% set array = [] %}`